# Ubuntu SDK installation error on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I followed the instructions from http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/get-the-sdk/.  But the installation failed with the following message at the end:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ubuntu-sdk : Depends: ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any idea why?  I have try to follow some of the similar problems already.  But none can help so far.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 0):

There was a major bug that is resolved. Remove the previous PPA and :

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk